# How do I remove domains from the network browser?

Tags: network, active-directory, domain, directory-utility

When I go to the network browser (in the Finder, hit command K, then click the "Browse" button, or just shift-command K), I see three domain names from a network I used to connect to six years ago. The appear in a list with dropdown trinagles to the left:

example.org
example.biz
example.com

How can I remove those? The computer was bound to an Active Directory domain, but nothing I try in the Directory Utility seems to remove them.

This was true on 10.5, 10.6, 10.7, and now on 10.8.

I will not wipe the system and start virgin for something like this that is not causing a problem but annoys me.

Answer (score 1):

When this periodically happened to me, it had to do with permissions being incorrect in the following areas, preventing me from making changes:

In **Snow Leopard (10.6)** and later

1. Open `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist` in a plist editor
2. Find the section `favoriteservers`
3. Remove listings for those stubborn locations

In **Tiger (10.5)** and earlier (if I remember correctly)

1. Navigate to `~/Library/Favorites`
2. Add/Remove the files with the pesky server names

Hope this helps